# Adding SMB to Windows, how safe is this?

Tags: windows, registry, smb

I came across a small hack, which claims it enables smb:// on windows.
The complaint was that things like `<a href="\\computername\path\file.ext">text</a>` weren't working.
While true that you can use file:///// in your url's, the user wanted to use smb:// so that it's cross-platform.

The hack goes as follows:
1) Create this Reg file, save and execute it:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\smb]
@="URL:smb Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\smb\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\smb\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\smb\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\smb.bat\" \"%1\""
```

And then create the smb.bat file in your C-folder, containing this:

```
@echo off
cd C:\
set url=%~dpnx1
explorer \%url:~7%
exit
```

My question: how safe is this, and any other thoughts on the matter? Besides the file:///// thing I mean.

Comment: I didn't test, but maybe adding the "Source Filter"={E436EBB6-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770} (from file:// protocol) in the [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\smb] may trick windows thinking that smb:// it's a file:// class url and apply the same protection. That would solve the main problem of supporting smb:// by this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it looks *damn* dangerous because it allows **any website** to place "\\RESOURCENAME" URLs, which will work regardless of context, and `smb.bat` will be called if you click such a link. I don't entirely understand the batch syntax (the ~ part especially) but it seems to me it's possible to pass any kind of argument to `explorer.exe`.

There's probably no immediate danger because it's very unlikely an outside attacker would guess you have this set up. Still, safe it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd much rather have the server detect windows clients output \servername\path scheme for those and smb:// for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Not to mention, SMB isn't the only protocol that uses that syntax, so does any other filesystem such as WebDAV. Somewhat clever idea though, and I wish that smb:// worked too.