# Open a direct file on the hard drive from firefox (file:///)

Tags: html, security, firefox, web-applications

I have a small php system i created for myself. This system contains a few .doc and .docx file documents. I want to be able to open them directly from the browser and not downloading them.

I created a link:
    `<a href="file:///c:/mysite/myfile.docx">myfile</a>`
But FireFox does not open the link. While `href="http://localhost/myfile.docx"` works fine - it offers me to download the file.

Any ideas how can i do it?
Maybe change something in firfox options / security settings?
And if you are at it, is there any chance to do it in IE8?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question???

Comment: Sounds to me like you picked the absolute wrong technology to do what you want.  Try something a little more geared to desktop development.

Comment: I'm here because of the same question, because until recently I _was_ able to do what was requested here, the solution was to follow the instruction on this page:http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don't_work#Disabling_the_Security_Check in short you'll need to create a user.js file with a couple configuration changes. These policies I suppose were deemed dangerous enough that you can't set them using about:config. Well that was what only seemed a couple months ago, In the last week I tried and now I get the same local file behaviour as chrome...

Comment: That is you can browse the files in a built-in file explorer in a tab, and the files will _download_ if you click on them. Why the hell would anyone want to download a file that is a local?! These security settings are generally used for intranet advantage where people are used to using the local/network filesystem and web programming being easy and familiar we're trying to slowly bring people over. So if anyone manages to figure out a way around this latest, "helpful" update, please let us know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although i still think it is a programming question, it was answered here:
https://superuser.com/questions/103026/open-a-direct-file-on-the-hard-drive-from-firefox-file

Both Firefox and IE8 support the [File URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

> Here are some examples valid for
>   Windows systems, referring to the same
>   file c:\WINDOWS\clock.avi
>
> > file://localhost/c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> >     file:///c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> >     file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> >     file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
>
> While the last is the most obvious and
>   human-readable, the first one is the
>   most complete and correct one.

Apparently (from the same url):

> Mozilla browsers refuse to follow file URLs on a page that it has fetched with the HTTP protocol.

but:

> Mozilla browsers can be configured to override this security restriction as detailed in Mozillazine's "[Links to Local Pages Don't Work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work)".

Answer (score 2):

Access to local files in Firefox can't be done unfortunately due to security restrictions. As far as I know (I have asked here repeated times myself) it's not even possible to allow select sites through a configuration setting or similar.

There is a workaround (ponentially unsafe and to be handled with care), you could register a custom protocol as outlined in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079276/adding-smb-to-windows-how-safe-is-this/2079290#2079290).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Which syntax did you use? The correct syntax for e.g. `c:/path/to/file.ext` would have been `file:///c:/path/to/file.ext`.</strike> **Edit:** not relevant anymore as OP has edited his question to include the syntax.

Note that this doesn't work at all if the file is stored at the server machine which in turn is a *physically different* machine than the client machine (where the webbrowser runs).

Comment: I updated my question to show that i used this syntax: `file:///c:/path/to/file.ext`.

Comment: It works fine here. Your problem lies somewhere else. Either the file is not there where you think it is, or Firefox is actually blocking with this. If you can ensure that last is the case, consider moving to superuser.com as this has nothing to do with programming anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I used symlink for windows added that file to my resources folder by creating symlink. 
How to create symlink shown here for windows
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html

That worked for me while same problem.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Security restrictions are a big issue when trying to access a file outside of your project. What I would recommend (if you are using IIS 7+), is to create a virtual directory to the folder that contains your docs on your C drive. Then you can access your files from the C drive by using the VP name and the host/localhost will be included in your url rather than the `"file:///"`.

However, if you are using IIS Express, you will have to manually add the virtual directory by updating the `"applicationhost.config"` file. Take a look at this link for more detail on how to set that up.

http://bhagirath-j-patel.blogspot.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My working code to open locally uploaded Files via Firefox (51.0) and the actual Internet Explorer (11).

```
$pfad = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes(urldecode($_REQUEST['pfad']))));
$datei = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes(urldecode($_REQUEST['file']))));
exec ('start c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\explorer.exe /select /seperate /n, /e, '.str_replace('/','\\',$pfad).utf8_decode($datei));
```

saved as open.php

"pfad" is a path BELOW the local Webroot (in my case customer folder)
while "file" is - of course - the file which I want to open.

I call it like so: ...href="open.php?pfad=<my_path>&file=<the_file>"

where both parameters are urlencoded