# DataNavigateUrlFields navigating to subfolder instead of correct location.

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid that needs one of the fields to hyperlink to a document housed on another server. The path is in this format: `\\server\location\file.doc`, but when I click on the cell in the data grid it becomes: `http://myASPServer/Subfolder/server/location.file.doc`. Is there any way that I can force this to go to the correct location? I know that you can prevent this for external websites by adding ftp:// or http://, but this does not seem to work for opening up this server location. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your answer can be found here on the asp.net forums http://forums.asp.net/t/1140909.aspx/1 - accepted answer from there below for your convenience.

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink Text="TextField" id="myHL" runat="server"
 NavigateUrl='<%# "file:///" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Path").ToString() %>'></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I believe you need to prefix your links with `file:///` for it would be `file:///\\server\location\file.doc`

Comment: Okay, I did that, and this is what I have: `<asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MSDSFileName").ToString() %>' id="filenameLink" runat="server"
                     NavigateUrl='<%# "file:///" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "serverFilename").ToString() %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>`. Now, when I try clicking on the link, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: When I scroll over the link, it has changed the url to start with file:///// instead of file:///\\. In firefox, if I look in firebug, the url is correct, but it doesn't seem to link properly.

Comment: Found this blog post http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2007/04/20/firefox-and-file-windows-unc-paths/index.html/ which explains whats happening and a work around - try it in IE and chrome and see what happens with those!

Comment: Oh and heres a Stack post which should also help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox