# Firefox: Image does not load on aspx code

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox

I just use simple code to load image in asp.net image control, it works fine in IE but firefox does't show image. the line of code is:

```
 string path = "F:\\Image\\";
    string img = "header-firefox.PNG";
    Image1.ImageUrl = path + img;
```

and the error is:

The address wasn't understood

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (f) isn't associated with any program.

even file:///F:/Image/header-firefox.PNG path is not working in code even.

Comment: Have you had a look in firebug at the call made when firefox tries to download the image?

Comment: It is probably been denied access

Comment: duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work

Comment: yes but what i do when access image file from server.

Comment: Where is the `F:` drive, on your server or client?

Comment: Here i put the just an example. but the image are exist on server.

Comment: Let me state the question a different way: if the images are on your server, why are you trying to use a file-access path to load them instead of setting them up within your web server software, to be hosted over HTTP?

Comment: Here's another SO question about the same thing:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that is the path you see in the HTML?  I understand that the backslashes are escaped in C# but surely in the HTML the path should be `"\\192.172.60.05\Users\4133.Png"`?

Have you tried navigating to \192.172.60.05\Users\4133.Png directly in Firefox?