# Open a Local drive on Website link click

Tags: c#

Is it possible to open a local drive on Website link click? Example, if i have a link called ArtWork. When user clicks this link, in the code behind i should do something to open D:/ArtWork . This is using C# in Asp.Net in VS 2005.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this will not work because most browsers refuse to open anchors (`<a>`) that have `href="file://..."` which is the only way that you could open the local hard drive of the user and point it to the `D:\ArtWork` directory.

[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox).

Answer (score 1):

The question is what you mean by "open D:\ArtWork".

If you want to do things (other than just upload) with the files:

In browsers that support it, you can use the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access).

> HTML5 provides very powerful APIs to interact with binary data and a user's local file system. The File APIs give web applications the ability to do things like read files [a]synchronously, create arbitrary Blobs, write files to a temporary location, recursively read a file directory, perform file drag and drop from the desktop to the browser, and upload binary data using XMLHttpRequest2.

If you wish to allow the user to just select a file from a folder and upload it:

> Ever since Microsoft ASP.NET was introduced with version 1.0, there has been the built-in means of building Web applications that had the ability to upload files to the hosting server. This was done through the use of the File Field HTML server control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx