# put a HTML link to the R Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I want to put a HTML link (actually it redirects to **file://...**) on the R Shiny user interface, so that end-users can just click it and go to that page in another tab in Chrome. Is there a way to do that? Where shall I put? In the ui.R file or in the server.R file?

I find a post here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/more-explorations-of-shiny/ but I am not sure how to use the `a()` function...

Note: I know how to do that (see my comments below), but since I am redirecting to a `file://` destination, the link won't work. Any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
doc <- tags$html(
   tags$body(
    a(href="http://www.lalala.com"))
)
cat(as.character(doc))

<html>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.lalala.com"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! actually I found adding `h5("Hello!", a("Link", href="file://blabla.html"))` will work, however since I am using `file://` instead of `http://`, when I click the link, there is no response. Do you know how to get the `file://` stuff done?

Comment: Under windows ...try this `file:///c:/folder/` or use local reference using sub directories...

Comment: thanks! unfortunately the HTML which `file://` points to is on a Unix server... and the /// method won't work...:(

Comment: @alittleboy see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox) for example....seems that you need 5 slash's....

Comment: sorry it still cannot open in a new tab. but if i choose to copy the link and paste and go in another tab, it works. I use chrome, and it seems it's not file:// friendly...

Comment: @alittleboy little bad question with a long infinite discussion! I dont' know if you are aware of this problem from the beginning or you discover them ...Looks like there are some workaround like installing this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida). I am not even sure that it can be considered as an R question now.

Comment: thank you so much for the extension information! at least for now I can get around it... :)