# No way to open local htm file in php?

Tags: xampp, localhost

Need to open an `htm page` that is located on my local disk. 
I'm running an application using `php and xampp server`. 
I've tried in every way and not make it. 
My application path is `C:\xampp\htdocs\portal`  
My htm file path is `C:\sistemas\test.htm`

I can't move my test file and put it into portal folder. 
when I click on the link just nothing happens.

here's my code

```
<li>
    <a target="_new" href="file:///C:/SISTEMAS/test.htm"> 
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-suitcase">&nbsp;</span> Test 
    </a>
</li>
```

I've tried in `Firefox 25 and IE10`. Same result.

Comment: Could it be that there's nothing between your <a></a> tags?

Comment: This is not related to PHP in any way. You can't get out of a virtual host (which probably points to `C:\xampp\htdocs\portal`) with the Apache default settings. Please get yourself an overview on basic Apache server configuration and how to work with vHosts. Or just move that file to the `portal` directory.

Comment: did you try anything else then your file ? may be google.com ?? see if it opens !

Comment: Aside from permissions problems, virtual host access problems, and the missing text in your anchor, maybe your file:// URI needs some love.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox

Comment: @martin.softpro Don't paste that code into comments, but edit your question!

Comment: "http://google.com" works good.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot actually do like this but I guess your requirement is just including the content of `test.htm`. Using php your code can go something like this.

```
<li>
    <a target="_new" href="test.php"> 
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-suitcase">&nbsp;</span> Test 
    </a>
</li>
```

and `test.php` would be including the content of `test.htm`

```
<?php require('../../sistemas/test.htm');  ?>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it in any other way. At least without using a server scripting language like php or asp.