# Browser Incompatibility with href="file..."

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I have a client that wants me to put a link to a folder on one of their networked servers. They additionally want this link to pull up the windows browser and go directly to the folder. As of IE11 I am able to do this with the following:

```html
<a id="A8" href="file:\\SomeServer\SomeFolder" target="_blank">SomePortal</a>
```

I should also note that the rest of the site I work at is on IE8, an upgrade to IE11 is eminent but until then I need a solution to my problem. This code does not work on IE8, Chrome, or FireFox the three browsers our clients are approved to use.

I have managed to convince my client to use Chrome for now since I have other HTML5 elements that IE8 will not support. So my question is this, is there some way to get Chrome to open this link in a windows browser? If not, can I get it to open in a new Chrome tab? If neither of these are options is possible, what is a good solution for making this compatible for another of the mentioned browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox

Comment: why dont you give path without `file` for E.g `href='\\SomeServer\SomeFolder'`

Comment: Unless VS debug is lying to me that does not work for Chrome either.

Comment: I read that question before posting mine. The reason I though mine was different is that in that question it dealt with opening a specific file. In my situation I just want to open the windows browser at the desired location.

Comment: I get local files working in IE11 using this format: `C:\User\Folder\file.ext`... while other browsers seem to use the format `file:///C:/User/Folder/file.ext`. Microsoft, why you gotta be like that?

Comment: when I use the IE accepted format of 'file:\\SomeServer\SomeFolder' in a blank tab in Chrome the address gets changed to 'file://SomeServer/SomeFolder' which opens the network location in the tab. Interestingly enough IE accepts both formats.