# Why doesn't my hyperlink work?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink

I have an asp.net page with a hyperlink tag, the idea is that I want to be able to click on the hyperlink (which will have the address of a directory on the system) and be able to open up the directory.

My hyperlink tag is within a gridview and the code for it looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="eFileHyper" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("hyperlink")%>' NavigateUrl='<%#Bind("hyperlink")%>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I have some code in the back end that adds "file:///" to the start of the address, like this:

```
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = CType(Session("newEFileTable"), DataTable)

    dr("lastUpdated") = Now
    dr("hyperlink") = "file:///" & hyperLink.Text
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    ' Update session table
    Session("newEFileTable") = dt

    ' update gridview - This binds the Session to the gridview
    BindEFileData()
```

If I enter in a directory like this \\server\directory\subdirectory it appears as - file:/// \\server\directory\subdirectory and it works fine.

If I enter a directory as C:/directory/subdirectory it appears as file:///c:/directory/subdirectory but clicking on it does nothing.

Why would one of these work but the other doesn't?

**Update** The \\server\directory\subdirectory and C:/directory/subdirectory are unrelated. The C:/ one is of course local, the other one is an address to a file on the server.

Comment: The url format is correct. It does nothing at all or redirect to incorrect place?

Comment: It does nothing at all, I click on the C:/ one and nothing happens

Comment: Create a file that just has `<html><body><a href="file:///c:/temp">temp</a>
</body></html>` in it, open in the browser and see if the link works.  Works for me--if it doesn't work for you then I'd look for a browser setting that disables this.  Also, the behavior is different between browers--Chrome renders the directory listing in the browser, while IE opens an Explorer window.

Comment: Yup I figured that out already Tony :), I've been trying with IE. When I try it in Chrome it just opens the directory listing in the browser like you say, which is ok too. I'll try what you suggest with the new html file.

Comment: @TonyHinkle the html you gave me works too, I'm not sure why that isn't working with the asp hyperlink tag

Comment: You're right--I renamed that little file to .aspx and put it on the server, and the link doesn't work when it is served up...

Comment: Hmmm maybe I should use <a> instead of <asp:hyperlink> then?

Comment: I used just a simple <a> tag, and when the page is served by IIS the link doesn't work.  I assume that it's a security feature of browsers.

Comment: See simlar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox

Comment: Have you done a view source to see if the href is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of browsers disable links that point to local content (unless the link is in a file) as a security feature.

See [Workaround for href="file://///..." in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox)

Also, search for "iis enable local file links" and you get lots of hits.  It looks like you can work around this by disabling relevant IE security: https://superuser.com/questions/149068/how-to-add-a-local-file-to-trusted-zone-in-ie8.  I can't test that right now as I'm at work and browser settings are locked down.