# href not opening files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am presenting all paths from some folder on the webpage and for files resisting but unfortunetly being on webpage and clinking on that links files are not opening, just nothing happened.

This is how I am doing loop to see all files:

```
@For Each item As String In Model
        @<a href="file:///@item">@IO.Path.GetFileName(item)</a>@<br>
 Next
```

Then all filenames are poping up, when I move my mouse on some of them I see:

```
file:///D:/somefolder/file.txt
```

But when I am clicking nothing is happening.

Comment: This might be seen as a security issue by the browser since it will try to open up the file on the local machine not the server.

Comment: See BalusC's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox

Comment: Do those paths represent files on the *client*, or files on the *server*?

Comment: Those files are placed on the server where i am debugging my program. What can i do this to work?