# How to create a link to external URL in Angular 2

Tags: hyperlink, angular, external, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I am new to Angular. I am starting with ver. 2.
I need to link to a `file://...` URL.
I tried normal `href`:

*Note:  `app` is a model object of the web which deals with applications.*

```
<a target="_blank" href="file://{{app.outputPath}}/index.html">no link here</a>.
```

That doesn't work - the link is there, with correct URL, but Angular seems to block the event somehow. Why?

So I've seen `ng-href` but that's for Angular 1.x. And [there's no `*ngHref`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/#!?apiType=Directive) from what I can tell. So this was just a naive try:

```
<a target="_blank" *ngHref="file://{{app.outputPath}}/index.html">over a directive</a>.
```

Also I have seen something with routing but that appears to be intended only for internal links within the application:

```
<a [router-link]="['/staticReport', {path: app.outputPath}]">see the report</a>.
```

`app.component.ts:`

```
@RouteConfig([
    ...
    {path:"/staticReport/:path", redirectTo: 'file://  ???? ' }
])
```

What's the way to create an external link?

Comment: Have you checked what the URL looks like that is generated in the DOM? (contexte menu on the link "Inspect element"). Actually "`app` is a model object of the web which deals with applications" doesn't provide much information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume `app` is assigned async. You can work around this using the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator):

```ts
<a target="_blank" href="file://{{app?.outputPath}}/index.html">no link here</a>.
```

to not break the binding when Angular tries to resolve it before `app` actually has a value.

**Original**
This worked for example:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
  <a target="_blank" [href]="'file://' + outputPath + '/index.html'">no link here</a>
`
})
export class App {
  outputPath:string = 'www.google.com';

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
  }  
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IvTzuJ?p=preview)

Actually, your first example works fine as well

```ts
<a target="_blank" href="file://{{outputPath}}/index.html">no link here</a>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pamdfw?p=preview)

Comment: The URL value is ok. The link is there, and the `href` value is ok too. What seems to happen is that Angular2 somehow discards the click on that link.

Comment: When you change the `file://` to `http://` the link works fine. With `file://` and error message is printed to the console (Not allowed to load local resource: file://www.google.com/index.html). I don't see anything wrong with the link in Angular2.

Comment: I guess this is a browser issue not an Angular issue. It works fine with a `http://` URL which IMHO doesn't make it look like Angular interferes with such links.

Comment: Seems you're right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317834/workaround-for-href-file-in-firefox

Comment: So the issue reported as example on Angular JS docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref): "<a href="....gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>", where AngularJS might not have a chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value before the user click on it, does it still apply to Angular 2? 
If still the case, using href="...{xxx}"> would still lead to the same problem.

Comment: @Francesco this answer (and the question) is about Angular, not Angularjs.

Comment: @Günter sorry if I pose the question not clearly enough. From your last comment, then I get that the same issue does not affect Angular (as it was for AngularJS). Thanks

Comment: I see. I stopped reading when I sale the `docs.angularjs.org` link - sorry. No, Angular2 works differently. The bindings like `{{}}` are resolved before the component is added to the DOM, therefore the browser never gets `{{}}`. If you use AoT compilation, these bindings are resolved even before anything is loaded into the browser.

Comment: sidenote: the '?' is not the "Elvis Operator" - it's the "Optional Chaining Operator"

Comment: Never heard that name. Only Elvis or safe-navigation. Do you have a link to TS docs where it is used as official name?