# How to Create Angular Internal URL Hyperlink?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-routing

How do I create URL for an internal link?

Say user in on Customer Component page, and wants to go to Product page.

```
http://localhost:4200/app/customer
```

There is textbox in the Component which states **Product:**
How can they route to Product Page in Angular Typescript and HTML?

```
http://localhost:4200/app/product/{ProductName}

http://localhost:4200/app/product/ComputerKeyboard

http://localhost:4200/app/product/Book
```

The baseURL may change also, depending on port numbers, environment eg:

```
http://www.TestEStore.com/app/product/ComputerKeyboard

http://www.TestEStore.com/app/product/Book
```

Its also needs to do html encoding, since html encoding eg spaces are encoded as %20, etc

**Trying to edit code :**

```
let productName: string = 'Computer Keyboard';

<a href="{{Whats the variable name?}}/product/{{this.productName)}}">Computer Keyboard</a>
```

Is there better option in Angular?

Resource: [How to create a link to external URL in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082785/how-to-create-a-link-to-external-url-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you should do:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/app/product/', productName]">Product</a>
```

Use the routerLink directive so the angular router can navigate to the proper component. Don't use href attribute on  for internal links as that will do a full postback which will reload your application.

Comment: maybe you can answer this one, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585303/angular-router-avoid-hyperlink-url-encoding