# Object tag with type = "application/pdf" not issuing GET method to download PDF

Tags: html, pdf

I'm working on an application that embeds PDFs into a webpage using the `<object>` tag. Here is the HTML that I'm using:

```
<object data = "C:/full/path/to/some_file.pdf" type = "application/pdf" width = "100%" height = "100%">
<p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser. 
<a href = "file:///C:/full/path/to/some_file.pdf">Click here to download the file.</a>
</p>
</object>
```

The paragraph about not having the PDF plugin pops up and the link is there with the correct filepath, but when I click the link nothing happens. What could be causing this? I thought it might be the preceeding "file:///", but when I remove that I get the error about "c" not being associated with any programs.

Here is the (very!) basic structure of my page:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <iframe src = "dynamically_generated.html">
      <html>
       <head></head>
       <body>
        <object type = "application/pdf" ...></object>
       </body>
      </html>
     </iframe>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If more information is needed, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: are you loading the page containing this `<object>` tag via http? e.g. a full-blown url? IF so, you can't use local urls in a page originating from "outside".

Comment: No, I'm loading the page containing the `<object>` tag as an iframe. I'll update my question to show the basic structure of the page.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you must need to load it using an `object` tag?

Comment: No, not at all. I was only doing that based on what I was reading online. I'm a total HTML rookie, so I'm definitely open to suggestions.

Comment: You may want to try embedding the PDF file within an iframe to use the built-in browser PDF reader (almost everyone came with one these days) or for maximum compatibility, something like [PDFjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is the linking to the PDF document, then you could try by changing the URLs from absolute (meaning all the `file:///c:/...`) to relative by chaining it using `..` to go one level up, say, the HTML file is in the path `C:/full/path/to/file.html` and the PDF file is along (in the same folder) as the HTML file, then you can just write `some_file.pdf` without the full path `C:/full/path/to/some_file.pdf`.

On Windows, and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), all of these are valid paths for a local file:

```
file://localhost/c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
file:///c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
```

The preceeding `file:///` is important because it tells the browser it's a local file and not a file somewhere in a website.

Be aware though that some browsers ([Firefox included](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work)) will refuse to link to a local file from a web URL (starting with `(http|https)://`) so that may give you problems as well (for more information, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177136/1012139)).

Comment: So I finally figured out what the problem was. There were essentially three things going wrong: 1) working directories and paths, which you addressed above, 2) trying to use both http://localhost and file://, which you also seem to address above, and 3) my file name wasn't allowed to have spaces in it. Lots of stuff going on, but I was finally able to get it, so thanks for the input!