# Java tzupdater throws Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: c

Tags: java, windows

I followed the [Oracle > Known Issues > Version issue since tzdata 2016g release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html#issues) and created a file named `tzdata2016g.tar.gz` on `C:\` drive.

Executing (on Windows 2008 R2):

```
java.exe -jar c:\tzupdater.jar -l file://C:/tzdata2016g.tar.gz -v
```

Returns:

```
Using file://C:/tzdata2016g.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
java.home: ---
java.vendor: Oracle Corporation
java.version: 1.8.0_102
tzupdater version 2.1.0-b04
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2016d
Error encountered while downloading file://C:/tzdata2016g.tar.gz
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: Error encountered while downloading file://C:/tzdata2016g.tar.gz
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: Error encountered while downloading file://C:/tzdata2016g.tar.gz
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.downloadFile(ExternalModule.java:70)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:205)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:643)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: C
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:952)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:917)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1012)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:998)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:294)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.downloadFile(ExternalModule.java:44)
        ... 2 more
```

Pasting the URL `file://C:/tzdata2016g.tar.gz` in Google Chrome works (the file is found and downloaded).
Tried multiple slashes and CaSiNg the `C` drive, but nothing helps.
Also tried `file://localhost/C:/tzdata2016g.tar.gz` and other [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177136).

Any ideas?

Or maybe someone created the tzdata2016g.tar.gz and cares to share? Maybe I did something wrong when created it...

Comment: I'd try adding one or more `/` after `file://`.

Comment: The error is then changed to `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ... (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Answer (score 1):

First, download the files from: https://github.com/kumlali/tzupdater_2016g_workaround

Then, run with three slashes after `file`:

```
java.exe -jar c:\tzupdater.jar -l file:///C:/tzdata2016g.tar.gz -v
```