# Using javascript to open a shell

Tags: javascript, shell

Is there a reliable crossbrowser way to open up a shell using javascript (e.g. explorer.exe)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible as it would be a (gaping) security risk.

Comment: Disregarding the gaping security risk it would be awfully convenient for me ;)

Comment: @kustnodi, Too bad. The browser environment is meant to be sandboxed.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible for security reasons. Accessing ***client machine*** is the problme here !

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the client machine, and the client machines are all Windows XP or later, there actually is a way by defining a custom protocol as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079276/adding-smb-to-windows-how-safe-is-this) (Mozillazone article [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol)).

That way, you can create links like `my_custom_protocol://helloworld.txt` that cause an explorer window to be opened in Windows.

This potentially opens a (however remote) security hole, as connecting a custom protocol to `explorer.exe` could be used to send arbitrary parameters to that executable. Make sure you are aware of the security implications; depending on your situation, it might work for you, though.